# Why does executing `git status` change the result of subsequent `git diff-index`?

Tags: docker, git

consider:

```
$ git --version
git version 2.20.1 (Apple Git-117)
$ git diff-index --quiet HEAD ; echo $?
1
$ git status > /dev/null
$ git diff-index --quiet HEAD ; echo $?
0
```

This is on macos with a case-insensitive file system. (I don't know that that is relevant.)  On the host where this occurs, there is a docker image running debian with that same directory mounted, and in the docker image, the opposite behavior occurs:

```
$ git diff-index --quiet HEAD ; echo $?
0
# At this point, `git status` was invoked outside the docker image
$ git --version
git version 2.20.1
$ git diff-index --quiet HEAD ; echo $?
1
```

To be clear, the sequence of commands executed here is: `git diff-index` on the docker image (returns 0), `git diff-index` on the host (returns 1), `git status` on the host, `git diff-index` on the host (returns 0), `git diff-index` on the docker image (returns 1).

Basically, if I run `git-status` in one environment, `git diff-index` will succeed (return 0) in that environment and fail in the other.  Any thoughts about what is going on?  This isn't a big deal, and I have a suspicion that the case insensitivity of the file system is to blame, but I'd love a solid explanation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've had a similar problem with `git diff-files` and I think the cause was the same. This doesn't need to involve Docker or case-insensitive filesystems, although these may exacerbate the problem.

Git maintains a cache of information about the content of files. Normally, this is transparent, and high-level commands such as `git status` and `git diff` update the cache as needed.

Lower-level commands like `git diff-index` and `git diff-files` are designed to return quick, but approximate results. They don't update the cache. They return 0 if they're sure that the things they're comparing are identical, but when they return 1, all it means is “I'm not aware that the things are identical”. If the cache entries are stale, it's possible that the things are identical but `git diff-xxx` doesn't know.

I don't know exactly how the cache works. In your first experiment, it seems that the first call to `git diff-index` noticed that the cache entry was stale, and so returned 1 for “I don't know”. Then `git status` updated the cache, and the second call to `git diff-index` saw valid cache entries and was able to conclude that the files are identical. In your second experiment, running `git status` outside the Docker container seems to have created cache entries that `git diff-index` inside the container considered to be stale, so the second call to `git diff-index` returned 1 for “I don't know”.

My solution was to forget about low-level commands and stick to `git diff --quiet`.